# Linearity assumption of logistic regression

Tags: regression, logistic, linearity

Do I have to check linearity assumption of logistic regression
(Log odds of outcome  with  continuous variable)

using graph of predicted logodds (by logistic regression) and continuous variable

Or

using graph with real logodds and continuous variable ?

I think the latter is right
In univariate setting, the first one should be perfect linear. 
Is it right?

Comment: I think it might be easier to check that the deviance residuals have no patterns.

Comment: Thank you for reply. But I wonder whether logodds should be made by predicted probability of regression , or each level's real log odds on continuous variable.

Comment: See https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=Hosmer+Lemeshow.

Comment: @whuber, the Hosmer & Lemeshow test is not considered valid. What do you have in mind there?

Comment: @gung We have a couple hundred posts referring to this test: among them they provide an indication of what one might consider doing to test goodness of fit.  I did not intend my comment to constitute or even suggest a recommendation of that test.

Comment: See https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/212867/problems-with-zero-values-when-testing-for-linearity-of-the-logit, https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/169348/how-should-i-check-the-assumption-of-linearity-to-the-logit-for-the-continuous-i?rq=1